# Customize pg_search to only show current user's content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, pg-search

I have a multiuser site, and I want users to be able to full-text multi-model search *only* their own content.

My Work model belongs_to: :users. Here's a snippet of work.rb :

```
class Work < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch
  belongs_to :user
  …
```

The ideal scenario would be something like this in my controller:

```
@results = PgSearch.multisearch('spring').where(:_user_id => current_user.id)
```

I was able to easily do this using the Searchkick gem with Elasticsearch by using this line of code:

```
@results = Searchkick.search query, where: {user_id: current_user.id}
```

I can't use Elasticsearch anymore unfortunately.

How can I implement similar functionality in pg_search?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just starting to work with PgSearch, but based on what I see, you can only apply filters on what data gets sent into their database pg_search_documents.  So you cannot isolate on a particular user for the search that you do later.  They simply concat the various fields into their content field and reference the model and record they came from. This allows easy searches to find the records which match the criteria, but then you have to post process the data.

To do what you're suggesting would require creating a search table for each user.

if you include the user_id in your against criteria (should be in the content), then you can post process the data quickly since the ID will be in the content.  If it is at the end of the :against list, it will be at the end of the content, so you can strip it off quickly and process against it

Comment: There is now a solution for this baked into pg_search, the additional_attributes feature — https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#more-options

Answer (score 0):

You can use pg_search_scope as described in [pg_search_scope](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#pg_search_scope)

in your case is [pg_search_scope multi-search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#configuring-multi-search)

Comment: I tried a similar approach already using the :if attribute. The problem is that I would need to call current_user from within my model. I managed to get the current_user object inside the model using a custom module even though you're not supposed to, but it broke the search indexing function.

`multisearchable :against => [:title, :year, :user_id], :if => lambda { |record| record.user_id == Current.user.id }`

Maybe you had a more elegant way to do this inside the model?

Thanks again

Comment: I have a workaround but I think it will not perform well at scale. The follow code can be loaded in the search controller `results = PgSearch.multisearch(query).map(&:searchable).select{|record| record.user_id == current_user.id }.sort_by(&sortField.to_sym)`   Would love a more elegant solution if anyone can suggest something.